# PHP returns radio button as text

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I'm trying to return a radio button markup from a PHP function:

```
function testRB(){
   echo '<input type="radio">';
}
```

However, it gets rendered in the browser (Chrome) as:

```
<input type="text">
```

I've tried it inside and outside of a `<form>` element.

I'm using `XAMPP` on a Windows 10 machine, and Netbeans as my editor.

Comment: I've tried it inside and outside of a `<form>` element.

Comment: Can you show an example of running your function? A script with just `testRB();` will only show a single radio button. Is the `view-source:<your website>` showing `<input type="text">`?

Comment: You might also want to include how you are calling `testRB`

Comment: I have it embedded on the html page:
` <?php testRB(); ?>`

I pulled resulting html from the Chrome developer console.

Comment: I commented out all my javascript and it's working. So it must be something going on there. Thanks.